# Callback in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have the following code which uses the `ajaxSuccess()` function. The problem I am facing is whenever an AJAX request completes successfully and jQuery triggers `the ajaxSuccess` event all `ajaxSuccess()` methods execute.

I think the better solution is to pass a callback but I'm not able to figure out how I can use it as I am new to it.

```
('#drop1').on('select2:select', (e) => {
    const selectedMake = e.params.data;
    utils.emptySelect2('#drop2');
    utils.emptySelect2('#drop3');
    utils.populateSelect2(`apiURL`, '#drop2');

    $(document).ajaxSuccess(() => {
        $('#drop3').select2('close');
        $('#drop2').select2('open');
    });
});
```

AJAX call:

```
populateSelect2(url, element, key) {
    $.get(url)
        .done((res) => {
            if (res) {
                let data = $.map(key ? res[key] : res, (obj) => {
                    obj.text = obj.name;
                    return obj;
                });
                data = sortBy(data, 'name');

                $(element).select2({
                    placeholder: 'please enter',
                    data
                });
            }
        })
        .fail(() => {
            this.showError(`Failed to call ${url}`);
        });
}
```

Comment: `.ajaxSuccess` is the global handler that will fire on every success of every ajax call.   You can pass an `ajax` object to select2 which can include a `.success` parameter or you can use the ajax object's `.done()` chain.   https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: You're defining a new `ajaxSuccess()` handler every time the `select2:select` event fires. That in itself is a problem. If you only want the logic in the ajaxSuccess to fire for certain AJAX requests then you will need to provide a callback function. How you do that depends on how you make the calls in the `populateSelect2` function. If you need help with that, we need to see the code of that function.

Comment: Could you share your ajax request code?

Comment: just added the ajax call code

Answer (score 1):

Inside `utils.populateSelect2` method you will be calling ajax calls to get the data. There you can maintain the success or failure callbacks. If you are directly attaching the ajaxSuccess method on document object then for all the successive ajax calls your ajaxSuccess method will be called.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '??',
        dataType: '??',
        success: function (data, status) {
            console.log(data.responseText);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just shared the ajax code above. I dont know how i can  pass a callback to utils.populateSelect2()

Answer (score 0):

When you use JQuery.ajaxSuccess() you 'catch' all the requests made from your browser. If you want to get the answer from one call in particular (which is often the case) you need to use a callback.

For exemple :

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/myUrl"
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

The 'data' parameter having the answer from the server.

P.S : You can replace your success callback with any function you'd like to use

Comment: I just shared my ajax call above, i don't have any idea how to use success callback

Answer (score 0):

jQuery ajax call snippet. Register success and error callback to receive api response.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/users/2",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){
            console.log("success");    
    },
    error:function(error){
        console.log("error");
    }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly you can do something like this:

```
('#drop1').on('select2:select', (e) => {
    const selectedMake = e.params.data;
    utils.emptySelect2('#drop2');
    utils.emptySelect2('#drop3');
    utils.populateSelect2(
        `apiURL`,
        '#drop2',
        // success callback
        (res) => console.log(res),
        // fail callback
        () => console.log(fail)
    );

    $(document).ajaxSuccess(() => {
        $('#drop3').select2('close');
        $('#drop2').select2('open');
    });
});

populateSelect2(url, element, key, success, fail) {
    $.get(url)
        .done((res) => {
            // ...

            success(res);
        })
        .fail(() => {
            // ...

            fail();
        });
}
```